# How to add a "service reference" in a asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, service-reference

I just found out that I get the "Add Service Reference" context menu option in a class library project but not in a "Web Site" project.

Now I am too far in this project and i need to use the Paypal Express Checkout option in my website. But when i add a web reference to the API, i do not get a `reference.cs` class. Is there another option to integrate the API.
If yes, a code sample would be great help.

Comment: So do you want to add a Serv ref or do you need `reference.cs`?

Comment: yeah, i want the reference.cs, actually adding a web reference does not avail me the class PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient which i need to call the SetExpressCheckout method

Comment: You should have the menu option... On the project root. And then the Service is added to an App_WebReference folder.

Comment: I only have the option to add a web reference, not a service reference.

Comment: Then you have an older .NET version... From before 3.5 ?  You could try to upgrade or use the imported Web reference... A Web ref could also work, depending on which features are used.

Comment: Oh my, indeed that is the problem, actually it's an old project and i didn't bothered earlier to upgrade it to 4.0, It might just work :) I'll try and get back

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman , upgrading to framework 3.5 got me the Add Service reference option. Dunno how i missed it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) suggested in the comments above,The option to add a Service Reference is available in .Net Framewrok 3.5 and above.

I upgraded my site to framework 3.5 and it worked out the way i wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

The following links could be useful: 
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal

The example uses HttpWebRequest to communicate with PayPal. Hope this helps.